# OKD : "Failed to upgrade helm release: create: failed to create: Request entity too large: limit is 3145728" when trying to upgrade helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, okd

Error: "Failed to upgrade helm release: create: failed to create: Request entity too large: limit is 3145728" when trying to upgrade helm version installed in OKD.

I believe the specified limit in the error is 3MB. I've added a .helmignore file and i don't have large sized files.

Any thoughts around this? Any way out for this problem?

Comment: I am not sure if there are extra files that are not used in deployment, if yes, try putting those to .helmignore file. In my case,  there were certain Licence file , Readme etc

Answer (score 2):

Search for a large file or binary accidentally copied under your helm base directory and move it to another location.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I encountered OP's same error because we upgraded the version of [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) used by our project.

In previous versions, Poetry would warehouse its virtualenvs in a "shared" cahce dir like `~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs`. However, after upgrading Poetry, the venv is now stored [in the project directory itself](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/108#issuecomment-392577866) alongside all the project files.

Once I realized this, I added `.venv` to our `.helmignore` file and was able to successfully `helm install` again.

For posterity, here's our `.helmignore` in full:

```
# Patterns to ignore when building packages.
# This supports shell glob matching, relative path matching, and
# negation (prefixed with !). Only one pattern per line.
.DS_Store
# Common VCS dirs
.git/
.gitignore
.bzr/
.bzrignore
.hg/
.hgignore
.svn/
# Common backup files
*.swp
*.bak
*.tmp
*.orig
*~
# Various IDEs
.project
.idea/
*.tmproj
.vscode/

values-generated.yaml
.venv
```